# R: Cut out rows based on condition and later add it to the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following dataframe

```
NAME;   YEAR;    VALUE
SA1;    1989;    23
SA1;    1990;    37
SA1;    1991;    -X
SA2;    2003;    56
SA2;    2004;    +X
SA3;    2007;    ST
SA3;    2008;    5
```

How can I cut out all the rows that contain a conditional statement (such as that the rows shouldn't contain +X, ST or -X)? I need the dataframe without those rows for processing and want to add the data later on to the processed dataframe.

Comment: By "columns" you mean rows?

Comment: Exactly…sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sorry I meant rows not columns!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED according to the changed question.

You may generate logical indices for rows based on your conditions. E.g.

```
row.ids <- apply(df, 1, function(a) any(a %in% c("-X","ST","+X"))
```

If row contains in any position one of the specified values it will be marked `TRUE`.
After you may split data.frame `df` on two parts

```
df1 <- df[row.ids,]
df2 <- df[!row.ids,]
```

The first `df1` will contain rows with specified values, the second `df2` will contain all other rows of initial `df`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many conditional statements,

```
 library(stringr)
```

If you read the dataset (`read.table`) with option `stringsAsFactors=F`, the character columns will not get coerced to factors. It is always possible to have extra spaces i.e. trailing or leading spaces.  Delete those before proceeding.

```
 dat[sapply(dat, is.character)] <- lapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.character)], str_trim)
```

Assuming that there are more columns in the dataset that have either `ST` or `-X` or `+X`, check for columns that have one of the values.  If any of those value is present, the column will be deleted.

```
 dat[,!colSums(dat=="+X"|dat=="ST"|dat=="-X")]
#  NAME YEAR
#1  SA1 1989
#2  SA1 1990
#3  SA1 1991
#4  SA2 2003
#5  SA2 2004
#6  SA3 2007
#7  SA3 2008
```

If you need to delete the rows that contain either of the above values

```
  dat[!rowSums(dat=="+X"|dat=="ST"|dat=="-X"),]
   #NAME YEAR VALUE
  #1  SA1 1989    23
  #2  SA1 1990    37
  #4  SA2 2003    56
  #7  SA3 2008     5
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use indexing for this.

```
dd<-data.frame(Name=c("SA1","SA1","SA1","SA2","SA2","SA3","SA3"),
           Year=c(1989,1990,1991,2003,2004,2007,2008),
           Value=c("23","37","-X","56","+X","ST","5"))

##values i do not want
NoThanks<-c("-X","+X","ST")

## data frame without the values you do not need
dd2<-dd[!(dd$Value%in%NoThanks),]

## maybe you want to save these in another dataframe
dd3<-dd[dd$Value%in%NoThanks,]

## then you can rbind them together later if you want (or other subsets)
dd4<-rbind(dd2,dd3)
```